# Looking for a plugin to convert geometry (or shapefile) to KML format for export

Tags: shapefile, kml, java

Java REST service has list of ***com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry*** and does some parsing to create a shapefile zip from it. Is there any plugin (or anything) so that I could use it in REST service to help me avoid manual KML content construction?

Comment: which java REST service?

Comment: It is in a custom written Java web application. I don't see the reason why you are asking this. I mentioned "Java rest" so it would be clear that I need to be able to apply the solution somewhere inside of my Java code.

Answer (score 1):

The [GeoTools library](http://geotools.org) provides everything you need to convert JTS geometries to a KML or shapefile. All you need to do is wrap them as SimpleFeatures and send the results to a datastore writer (for [shapefiles](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html)) or [an Encoder (for KML)](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/xsd/kml.html).

The following code converts a shapefile to kml for you:

```
    File infile = new File(args[0]);
    DataStore inputDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(
            Collections.singletonMap("url", URLs.fileToUrl(infile)));

    String inputTypeName = inputDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
    SimpleFeatureType inputType = inputDataStore.getSchema(inputTypeName);

    FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>
            source = inputDataStore.getFeatureSource(inputTypeName);

    FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>
            inputFeatureCollection = source.getFeatures();
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
    encoder.setIndenting(true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      encoder.encode(inputFeatureCollection, KML.kml, os );
      String out = os.toString().replaceAll("kml:", "");
      System.out.println(out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I think this should be it. As soon as I put it to the test will let you know